# Python Trouble with static class members in constructor

Tags: python, class, static

I am trying to write a game and I created a class for a Player. I wanted to keep the number of Players, as well as a list of Players stored as static members of the class, so I declared them outside the constructor function. Inside the constructor function I added code to increment the number of Players and add a new Player to the list.

```
class Player:

    nPlayers = 0
    player_list = []

    def __init__ (self):
        self.n = nPlayers + 1
        nPlayers += 1
        player_list += self
```

When I try to create a new object using the constructor I get the following error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nPlayers' referenced before assignment`

How can I fix this so that I can have such static variable function?

Comment: You really should read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still access them with `Player.`, even though they are static and an instance of the class:

```py
class Player:

    nPlayers = 0
    player_list = []

    def __init__ (self):
        self.n = Player.nPlayers + 1
        Player.nPlayers += 1
        Player.player_list.append(self)
```

Comment: @Oryx You may want to pick this as accepted answer. Thank u.